# How to get value of android:required (true or false ) attribute in uses-library tag?

Tags: android, xml, android-manifest

For example in androidmanifest.xml file there is below tag in an app A:

uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" android:required = "false"

How I can check in my app value of android:required attribute of App A?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PackageManager.getApplicationInfo() with the GET_SHARED_LIBRARY_FILES will return you a list of the libraries that are used in the ApplicationInfo.sharedLibraryFiles field.

However that won't tell you if the **required** attribute was true or false.  There is no API that tells you that - to find that out you will have to parse the manifest file of app A yourself.

Comment: @zmarties... Thanks for your reply. I also think so that there is no pubic API to know value of required attribute. There is only one solution that we can parse xml file and then put some checks and all but this is not a good approach. What you say?